# When is the checked variable in a let call released from the stack?

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to determine if `let` (and its sister functions) help conserve stack memory. Consider the following `let` statement:

```
fun bar() {
    foo().let { foo ->
        // foo is on the stack
        doSomething(foo)
    }
    // Is foo released from the stack here?

    doSomethingElse()

    // Or here?
}
```

TL;DR: when are checked variables released from the stack?

Comment: While this is a valid question, it's a little worrying…  I hope no-one's going to write code which relies on this sort of memory micromanagement!

Comment: @gidds it's very important for recursive algorithms

Answer (score 2):

`let` in Kotlin is simply an extension function that calls a function on a value. It's nothing special. Just like with regular functions, stack variables are dropped after exiting the scope of the function. You could also just do it with an explicit scope:

```kotlin
fun bar() {
    run {
        val result = foo()
        doSomething(result)
    }
    // result has been dropped
}
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you. I knew "let" is a function but for some reason I still thought of it as a statement.

Comment: Are you sure the stack vars are dropped, as the function is inline it should be inlined there and variables should live as long as parent function keeps alive in the stack. The scope is virtual imo (not present in the jvm bytecode).

Comment: @AnimeshSahu Interesting. I'll have to check that out.